# ASP.NET C# Dictionary inside a class is received empty when passed to another function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm sure it's quite a newbie question, but I see no other useful post, so pls, a little help will be appreciated.

I have a Dictionary inside a Class, and when I create a new object and pass it to another ASP.NET function, the class is correctly informed except for the dictionary, which has no elements.

Please, what am I missing to do??

This is the class

```
    public class Reparto
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> LecturaSalida { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        [Display(Name = "Lectura")]
        public string Lectura { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string JsonDictionary { get; set; }

        public Reparto()
        {
            //MVC asks for this
        }

        public Reparto(string ID, Dictionary<string, string> LecturaSalida)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.LecturaSalida = new Dictionary<string, string>(LecturaSalida);
            this.JsonDictionary = JsonSerializer.Serialize(LecturaSalida); // test to confirm dict is received
        }
    }
```

and this is the asp controller code (simplified)

```
       [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string ID)
        {
            try
            {
                Reparto DatosReparto = new Reparto(ID, Context.ObtenerReparto(ID));  // This populates DatosReparto object correctly
                return RedirectToAction("Reparto", DatosReparto);                    // And goes to the next point 
            }
            catch 
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ID", "Invalid!");
            }
            return View();
        }


        public IActionResult Reparto(Reparto DatosReparto) 
        {
            int test = DatosReparto.LecturaSalida.Count; // zero elements!!! while the other properties are correctly informed, as JsonDict which is correctly informed 4ex.

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
return RedirectToAction("Reparto", DatosReparto);
```

call:

```
return Reparto(DatosReparto);
```

Comment: But in this case, if I don't use RedirectToAction it remains in Index Action.
I can return View("Reparto") to change view, but when it submits executes Index action again.

Comment: Just try it. I always use this syntax. Doesn't matter where it  remains it will have the same result as RedirectToAction. It will return  View and Model  from Reparto.  if it had for example some  code and  return View("Reparto", DatosReparto)  it would return completely different result.